# KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I am sorry if this question is being asked because i missed something incredibly basic.

I am getting **KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary** from Unity for a search for a Dictionary Key.
Yet throughout my (still quite small) project i am successfully using MapLocation in other Dictionarys as a Key

I have stripped the code down to basics.

```
public class SpriteManager : MonoBehaviour {

Dictionary<MapLocation, GameObject> SpriteDictionary;

void Start(){
    SpriteDictionary = new Dictionary<MapLocation, GameObject>();

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            //Create Location Data
            MapLocation mLoc = new MapLocation(x, y);

            //Create GameObjects
            GameObject go = new GameObject();

            SpriteDictionary.Add(mLoc, go);
        }
    }
    MapLocation mTest = new MapLocation(0,1);
    Debug.Log("Dictionary entry exists?: " + SpriteDictionary.ContainsKey(mTest));
}
```

At the end the mTest of MapLocation(0,1) Debug line is giving me a **false**.

Here is the MapLocation code for completion.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class MapLocation {

    public int x;
    public int y;

    public MapLocation(){}

    public MapLocation(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to override `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(object obj)` of MapLocation, for example:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{        
    MapLocation m = obj as MapLocation;
    return m == null ? false : m.x == x && m.y == y;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return (x.ToString() + y.ToString()).GetHashCode();
}
```

Inside `YourDictionary.ContainsKey(key)` and `YourDictionary[key]`, use `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(object obj)` to judge equivalent. [Reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,bcd13bb775d408f1)

Comment: That works... but i have no idea how or why.
Can you point me to any resources so i can find out why this was necessary... and thank you for the correct response!

Comment: Update answer about inside Dictionary, i hope that help you

Comment: @Wibble If you're familiar with [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) - `GetHashCode` provides the index in the table, `Equals` resolves collisions.

Comment: Yes, thank you

Would it be best to use an `Array[int x, int y]` of MapLocations and call the individual MapLocations from there?
That way i would not be making `New` MapLocations to call from

Comment: @Wibble if you have always have `x` * `y` `MapLocations` instantiated, then I think using array might be simpler. The `Dictionary` would make sense if you mapped `GameObject` to a `MapLocation`: `Dictionary<GameObject, MapLocation>` implying that there aren't as many `GameObject` instances as `MapLocation` instances.

Answer (score 1):

*deyu note* is correct, when using custom types as the key in a dictionary, you must define `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. For interest, I've include alternative hashing algorithms.

The existing [`Point`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point(v=vs.110).aspx) class calculates the hash as follows:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return this.x ^ this.y;
}
```

Using *ReSharper* code completion:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  unchecked
  {
    return (this.x * 397) ^ this.y;
  }
}
```